# SVG map copied but not showing

Tags: html, svg

I copied an SVG map at the end of [this page](http://www.mehrnews.com/), that is map of Iran and I want to use it in my website.

I copied its code and paste it in a file what named map.svg and when I open it by Firefox that just show me the svg source!

**How to copy that source that show me the map?**

Comment: could you show code what you copied

Comment: @Panther please copy it from that website and test it

Answer (score 0):

I cannot post a comment because of my reputation level, but the svg you're trying to copy is working perfectly for me
make sure you copy everything between and including the tags `<svg> .. </svg>`

you will not get the styling and events, just a black SVG map

Comment: OK, That is not black.